# How to save the value of the selected item of a dropdown list in a session

Tags: php, jquery, session

I want to save the selected item of a dropdown-list in a session.
My call for the session looks like:

```
$('#airport-select').change(function(){

    $.ajax({
        url:"php/createSession.php",
        method:"GET",
        data: { 
            session_name: 'airportid', 
            session_value: $(this).val() 
        }
    })  
    .success(function(data){
        alert('Sucess');
    })
    .error(function(e){
        console.log("Erorr");
    });

});
```

And php :

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['session_name'])){

    $session_name='airportid';
    $session_value=$_POST['---'];
    $_SESSION[$session_name]=$session_value;
}
?>
```

The name of the session should be hardcoded as airportid . About the value im not sure.

Comment: it can be anything you like

Comment: please be aware that you are using `method:"GET"` in your ajax request, while the server **seems** to be expecting a POST request instead (from your php code).

Answer (score 2):

if it has to be hardcoded

```
 session_start();
 if(isset($_POST['session_name'])){
   $_SESSION['airportid']=$_POST['session_value'];
 }
```

or else

```
$_SESSION[$_POST['session_name']]=$_POST['session_value'];
```

edit, you have to also change `method:"GET",` to `method:"POST",`

Comment: Where do session_name and session_value come from?

Comment: From your data field,
data: { 
            **session_name**: 'airportid', 
            **session_value**: $(this).val() 
        }